# Cleaning up unmanaged resources from Session like Crystal Report Document

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, crystal-reports, session-state

My problem is that I have an ASP.Net application with crystal reports in it. I have to store the Crystal report's `ReportDocument` object in the session state, which is an unmanaged resource.

My question is: Will the `ReportDocument` object be disposed off on `Session.Abandon` or I will have to manually do it myself, and if I have to manually remove the `ReportDocument` object from the session state. What process should I follow, because at the `Session_End` event I would not know, what was the name of the object that was stored in `SessionState`, neither will be able to identify the `Key` with which the `ReportDocument` object is stored in the `Session`.

Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that when you store the object in the session you are simply serialising a copy of the objects current state, this copy won't be holding onto any unmanaged resources, but the original object will and you can just dispose of that after you have saved it to the session.

EDIT

Alternatively store all your reports in one session object that is a collection with a single key. e.g. List reports

Comment: I am using `InProc` Session Mode, so I don't need to serialize the copy of the object to be stored in the Session State or does the object serializes itself before being stored in the Session????

Comment: Yes you might be right, i don't think the object is serialised if you are using InProc session mode.  In that case can you explain why you don't know the key?  The key only needs to be unique per session e.g. session["report"] will work fine with multiple sessions and each session will get it's own version.  If you need to store many reports then store a collection of reports with a single key.

Comment: I have more than fifteen pages with each storing their own Crystal Reports Document in the session to make use of the Paging of Crystal Reports, which won't work if I don't put it in Session. I said that about the Key because there may be more pages added with more Document objects stored in the Session...

Comment: So store all your reports in one session object that is a collection with a single key.  e.g. List<CrystalReports> reports;

Comment: That seems to be a good idea... Can you put that in your answer, so that I may mark your answer...